TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getCroppedCanvas')
I want to crop the image to 1:1 ratio and convert it to url. but, an error similar to the title appears and says that the getCroppedCanvas function cannot be called. This is my code, can somebody help me ?:(
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Cropper from 'react-cropper';
import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ImageEditor = ({ uploadedImage }) => {
  const [cropData, setCropData] = useState("#");
  const cropperRef = useRef(null);
  
  const getCropData = () => {
    if (cropperRef.current) {
      console.log('click');
      const croppedCanvas = cropperRef.current.getCroppedCanvas();
      if (croppedCanvas) {
        const dataUrl = croppedCanvas.toDataURL();
        setCropData(dataUrl);
      }
    }
  };
        
  console.log(cropperRef.current.getCroppedCanvas); 

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <Cropper
          ref={cropperRef}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          zoomTo={1}
          aspectRatio={1}
          src={uploadedImage}
          viewMode={1}
          background={false}
          responsive={true}
          autoCropArea={1}
          checkOrientation={false}
          guides={false}
          data={{ width: '100%' }}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div
          className="box"
          style={{ width: "50%", float: "right", height: "300px" }}
        >
          <h1>
            <span>Crop</span>
            <button style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={getCropData}>
              Crop Image
            </button>
          </h1>
          <img style={{ width: "100%" }} src={cropData} alt="cropped" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br style={{ clear: "both" }} />
    </div>
  );
};

ImageEditor.propTypes = {
  uploadedImage:PropTypes.node
}
export default ImageEditor;

I wanted to use the crop function using the image src I currently have, but it didnt work.

You've provided two different vague descriptions of the error. What exactly is the error message, in full?

console.log(cropperRef.current.getCroppedCanvas)  this line is useless and could potentially be the source of an error. I'd recommend removing it

The problem is that getCroppedCanvas doesn't work. The reason I wrote console.log was to see if it worked.

Please [edit] your question to describe exactly how it's not working. Include any error message as text, in full (complete with stack trace).

Also, which version of react-cropper are you using? ref support was removed in 2.0.0 but added back in 2.1.0

The way I was referencing the Cropper instance was wrong.
const cropper = cropperRef.current.cropper;
I solved!
